# ADO.NET DAL и BLL

Tags: c#

***Есть два класса SqlHelper и класс DishesTypes используются как DAL***

```
public class SqlHelper{ 

    public static SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string procedure, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters){             
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))       
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(procedure, _connection)){                    
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddRange(commandParameters);
                return command.ExecuteReader();               
            }                  
        }    
    }

}

public class DishesTypes{

    public static SqlDataReader DishesTypesSelectAll(){
        return SqlHelper.ExecuteReader("DishesTypesSelectAllRows");//название хранимой процедуры
    }

}
```

***И есть класс DishedTypes который используется как BLL***

```
public class DishesTypes
{
    public int DishTypeId { get; set; }
    public string DishType { get; set; }


    public static List<DishesTypes> DishesTypesSelectAll()
    {

        IDataReader dr = DataAccessLayer.DishesTypes.DishesTypesSelectAll();          

        List<DishesTypes> dishesTypesList = new List<DishesTypes>();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            DishesTypes myDishesTypes = new DishesTypes
            {
                DishTypeId = (int)dr["DishTypeId"],
                DishType = (string)dr["DishType"]
            };
            dishesTypesList.Add(myDishesTypes);
        }
        return dishesTypesList;
    }
}
```

***При выполнении данного участка кода возникает ошибка***

```
while (dr.Read())
```

*Причина тому,соединение к этому моменту уже закрыто и нужно его заново открывать, как лучше изменить реализацию классов придерживаясь слоев DAL и BLL,чтобы заработало?*

Comment: Возвращайте `DataTable`. Для `SqlDataReader` нужно открытое соединение.

Answer (score 2):

DAL как правило всегда возвращает уже готовые для работы данные. Т.е. в нем открывается соединение, выполняется запрос, соединение закрывается и данные преобразуются к какому-то виду. Это могут быть объекты (POCO/DTO) -- вы можете сразу возвращать коллекцию объектов типа `DishesTypes`. Также это может быть `DataTable`.

У вас после выполнения метода `ExecuteReader` соединение закрыто, поэтому попытка прочитать данные из `SqlDataReader` терпит неудачу. Заполняйте коллекцию объектов/таблицу с данными внутри метода `ExecuteReader`.

Answer (score 2):

При первом взгляде на этот код напрашивается вопрос: если DishesTypes относится не к слою работы с данными, а к бизнес-логике, то почему он занимается извлечение данных из ридера? И зачем вообще бизнес-логике работать с IDataReader'ом - сущностью, которая по идее не должна выходить за пределы DAL? Я думаю, вам имеет смысл всю логику, связанную с получением данных из sql перенести во внутренности DAL, а из него отдавать уже сконструированные объекты. 
Иными словами, метод **ExecuteReader** должен возвращать не SqlDataReader, а уже сконструированный объект (в частности DishesTypes). Вполне возможно, что DishesTypes - не единственный класс, экземпляры которого вы хотите получать из результатов запроса. Поэтому можно сделать обобщенное решение. Например что-то наподобие:

```
public class SqlHelper
{ 
    public static List<T> GetData<T>(string procedure, Func<SqlDataReader, T> convertor,  params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
    {             
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))                   
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection))
            {                    
                 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 command.Parameters.AddRange(commandParameters);

                 var res = new List<T>();
                 var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                     res.Add(convertor(reader));  
                 }   
                 return res;                                       
            }                  
        }    
    }

public class DishesTypes
{
    public static List<DishesTypes> DishesTypesSelectAll()
    {
        Func<SqlDataReader, DishesTypes> convertor = // ф-ция, конвертирующая данные из ридера в DishesTypes
        return SqlHelper.GetData<DishesTypes>("DishesTypesSelectAllRows", convertor);
    }
}
```